# Deserialize JSON object to C# object that contains lists

Tags: restsharp

I what to use the Rest Sharp Deserialization but i don't know how to build the right class

The JSON :

> ```
>    {
>       "LIST_ID":34468,
>       "CREATED_PERSONAL_FIELDS":[],
>       "EXISTING_PERSONAL_FIELD_NAMES":[ ["41028","Test1"] , ["41029","Test2"] ]
>     }
> ```

I tried this class:

```
    public class PersonalFieldsAddResponse
    {
        public string LIST_ID { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> SUBSCRIBERS_CREATED { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> BAD_PERSONAL_FIELDS { get; set; }
    }
```

And this one:

```
    public class PersonalFieldsAddResponse
    {
        public string LIST_ID { get; set; }
        public List<string> SUBSCRIBERS_CREATED { get; set; }
        public List<string> BAD_PERSONAL_FIELDS { get; set; }
    }
```

The Deserialization does get me the LIST_ID but i always get NULL at SUBSCRIBERS_CREATED  and BAD_PERSONAL_FIELDS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

LOL,
it need to be :

```
        public class PersonalFieldsAddResponse
    {
        public string LIST_ID { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> CREATED_PERSONAL_FIELDS { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> EXISTING_PERSONAL_FIELD_NAMES { get; set; }
    }
```